# C# - Retrieve Custom Class Object from List

Tags: c#, list, class

So I have a custom class of "Spell".
At run time, several instances are created and added to the list "spellDB".

I want to be able to find a Spell in the list with the same ID as a declared value and add the found spell to the list. I keep getting an error that the property cannot be invoked as a method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please explain why none of result that you found by using a search engine (like http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+select+item+by+id+from+list) did not work. Side note: please avoid adding "thank you" notes to posts for reasons discussed in [this META post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var spell = spellDB.FirstOrDefault(sp=>sp.Id==ID);
```

This will give you the first object in the `spellDB` list whose `Id` equals the given id, `ID`. If there isn't any such an object, then the `spell` would be null.

Having found the object you want, it's trivial to add it to any list you want, just using the `Add` method of the corresponding list.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much - stupidly I was trying to cross variable types too so that was causing my errors.